# using jquery to add tr

Tags: jquery, html

I added a jquery function to add a `<tr>` dynamically at the end of my table. It worked fine until I added table headers to my table. After I did this, the function started adding 2 `<tr>`s at a time to the table. What happened?

HTML:

```
<table id="table" border="0">
<th>Col 1</th><th>Col2</th><th>col3</th>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value ="one">one</option>
            <option value="two">two</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
  $('a#add').click(function(){
    $('#table > tbody').append('<tr><td><select><option value ="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></input></td><td><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');  
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The browser is going to compensate for your code by surrounding your th with another tbody. Try surrounding the th's with a thead.

```
<table id="table" border="0">
    <thead>
        <th>Col 1</th><th>Col2</th><th>col3</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value ="one">one</option>
                    <option value="two">two</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `tbody`, you need to use `thead` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `:last` to your selector like so ([demo](http://jsbin.com/ijosa4), [source](http://jsbin.com/ijosa4/edit)):

```
$(function(){
  $('a#add').click(function(){
    $('#table > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><select><option value ="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></input></td><td><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');  
    return false;
  });
});
```

Since your headers are not part of `tbody` or `thead`, the browser automatically creates a `tbody` for them. Thus your rendered table has **two** `tbody`s. **The better solution** is to keep your current selector and **put the header in a `thead` section** like this:

```
<thead>
<th>Col 1</th><th>Col2</th><th>col3</th>
</thead>
```

Or just put it in the already existing `tbody` so the browser won't make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `> tbody` from you jQuery selector. It worked fine for me after that.

```
$('a#add').click(function(){
  $('#table').append('<tr><td><select><option value ="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></input></td><td><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');  
});
```